# Module 'numpy' has no attribute linespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I tried this piece of code but it kept giving me the same error. I'm sure I have no other script named `numpy` in the directory. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling it but nothing works.

```
import numpy as np; from numpy import pi
theta = np.linespace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)
```

When ran, it returned `module 'numpy' has no attribute 'linespace'`. In fact, no other modules works, any idea why?

Comment: You have made a typo, it should be `np.linspace()` instead of `np.linespace()`

Comment: `np.linespace` must be `np.linspace`. If you use `np.pi`, there is no need to use `from numpy import pi`. There is no need to import it again.

Comment: I faced the same spelling issue in torch , torch.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its `np.linspace()` instead of `np.linespace()`.